# Is there a conditional javascript code to insert url specific meta values?

Tags: javascript

I would like to insert a custom meta value into a specific page only. This site is very old and database driven, creating custom meta field is not an option.

I would like to insert a javascript function, that could insert a meta value for a specific URL only?

```
<META name="my-advertisement" content="none">
```

into `/about-me`

I have tried multiple conditional codes I have found online but not have helped. It does not insert into the header section with the page meta title etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (document.location.pathname === '/win') {
        $("head").append('<meta name="mrf-advertisement" content="" />');
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: why are you waiting for document ready? And not sure how you are checking for it to be on the page. Adding it with JavaScript sort of defeats the purpose of them.

Comment: What's in the console? Any errors, indications of problems running the code. etc.

Comment: It seems like this should work. Maybe the problem is that the code that looks for the meta tag is running before your code adds it. Try taking it out of `document.ready`, and put it before any other `<script>` tags.

Comment: I checked it - with an otherwise empty HTML this works. With document ready or otherwise.

Comment: No errors running the code sample, I have been checking the console but I guess it would need to be in the page source? I will give these suggestions a try.

Comment: As @epascarello mentioned, using javascript to add the meta tag to the HTML won't have the expected result. This is because the tools that are scanning for the meta tags are most likely using the actual HTML page source on load and not any coded modified via javascript. Your best bet would be to find a server side solution instead as going the javascript will most likely be a hopeless endeavor.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments - We created a field in the database for the particular field as javascript did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm using the answer field.

Based in your question I'm supposing that you have permission to write `<script>` tags in `<head>`, if is it right, you could try to do in this way:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>

 <script>
  if(true) // change to => if (document.location.pathname === '/win')
   document.write( '<meta name="mrf-advertisement" content="" />' );
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```